# How to determine it's a WebSQL or Sqlite database?

Tags: sqlite, cordova, web-sql

Pardon if this sounds noob.

We are current working on a mobile application that utilizes the Cordova framework. We would need to store data on the device, and such had decided on to use a database system.

We understand that for db storage, Cordova supports the WebSQL API, but since currently W3C stopped the development on WebSQL, we would wish to use a native SQLite database.

However, we do have a database file that are created via the WebSQL API. I understand that WebSQL actually utilize SQLite underneath(correct me if i'm wrong), but would the file display the characteristic of a WebSQL database? such as the file size limitation on mobile device?

Answer (score 0):

The file size limitation is implemented in the particular copy of the SQLite library that is used to access the database, not in the database file itself.

Please note that W3C's (lack of) endorsement does not necessarily influence whether Cordova continues to use WebSQL.

Comment: as such, is there a particular difference between WebSQL and a SQLite database library?

Comment: WebSQL implementations typically disable some features, but otherwise they use a normal copy of SQLite.